# Prevent ISE from bitswapping the configuration file

Tags: xilinx, ise, selectmap

For some reason unknown to me, ISE provides a bitswapped configuration image: each byte has its bits swapped.

Is there a way to disable this bitswapping? (Having to do it again in C code slows down the image loading.) I've had a look at the `Bitgen` options and was surprised to not see what I wanted there.

Comment: You mentioned selectmap in the tags. Is that how you are loading the bit file?

Comment: @BrianCarlton: Yes. It's more convenient in my case (given the hardware configuration) for the bits to be in the reverse direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to feed PROMGen the `-b` option to disable bit swapping. This is described in the [Command Line Tools User Guide](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx13_1/devref.pdf) in Chapter 17, page 255. But it also describes how to access PROMGen in the Project Navigator (ISE) GUI.

Comment: Thanks, but [it seems](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx11/pim_p_creating_prom_file_xilinx_prom.htm) that the option is not a compilation option for ISE, but rather for iMPACT *after* compilation, as an extra step. I just want my `.bin` files without bit-swapping produced during compilation.

Comment: I got confused by the statement, "There is also an
interactive version, called the PROM formatting wizard that you can access from inside Project Navigator (see the iMPACT Help)." Since it mentioned Project Navigator, I assumed there was a setting in ISE. But you're right, it's in iMPACT. Or via [command line](http://www.xilinx.com/support/answers/35686.htm)

Answer (score 1):

BIN files are designed to be streamed serially, so have the bits in the order that the device expects them.

If you need a different order, PROMGen is where it's at I'm afraid, as a postprocess on the bitfile.